How can I deal with conditional exceptions in typescript?
I have this typescript code:
const loadSomething = () => {
  try {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    throw e
  }
}

const main = () => {
  const result = loadSomething()
  console.log(result.foo)
}

This code is totally fine and does not produce any typescript issues. But now I want to outsource the code which I use for handling the exception. So I change it like this:
const logError = (e: any, rethrow: boolean) => {
  console.error(e)
  if (rethrow) {
    throw e
  }
}

const loadSomething = () => {
  try {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  } catch (e) {
    logError(e, true)
  }
  return undefined
}

const main = () => {
  const result = loadSomething()
  console.log(result.foo)
}

I need to conditionally throw that exception, but in that case typescript gives me the error that result is possibly undefined. But this can never occur, since I rethrow the exception in the catch block. Is there a way I can tell typescript that logError throws an exception if rethrow is true, so that the typescript issues are gone?

Better write throw logError(e); instead of logError(e, true) (and logError(e); instead of logError(e, false)).

You could declare a overload function logError(e: any, rethrow: false): void; function logError(e: any, rethrow: true): never;?

@Bergi That won't work since it will throw undefined even if the condition isn't met.

@Etheryte I meant for logError to return the error of course. Instead of conditionally throwing and deciding via a boolean flag argument, leave the decision to put the throw in the code to the caller. Less weird code, more type safety.

@Bergi It seems I wasn't very clear with what I mean. Throwing whatever logError returns defeats the whole purpose of conditionally throwing. Regardless of the check, it will always throw. But if you move the check up one level you're back to the original code.

"Is there a way I can tell typescript that logError throws an exception if rethrow is true, so that the typescript issues are gone?" - I think you can do it with some conditional type voodoo, such that never is asserted instead of undefined when the type (not the value) of rethrow is true. But a simpler way is to replace your single logError function with two separate functions: logErrorAndSwallow and logErrorAndThrowUp with corresponding return types (...and now this SO thread has a parental advisory warning)

Does this answer your question? How to declare a function that throws an error in Typescript

@Etheryte Passing true will also always throw. I think throwing based on a parameter is not a good practice here. Maybe the example is oversimplified?

Thanks @Bergi for your answer. So I changed my code to this and have no typescript issues anymore:
function logError(e: any, rethrow: false): void
function logError(e: any, rethrow: true): never
function logError(e: any, rethrow: boolean) {
  console.error(e)
  if (rethrow) {
    throw e
  }
}

const loadSomething = () => {
  try {
    return {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  } catch (e) {
    logError(e, true)
  }
}

const main = () => {
  const result = loadSomething()
  console.log(result.foo)
}

